# Set font through calligraphy to all buttons in an Application

Tags: android, android-activity

I've seperated my UI part into a lib and am creating my styles there.

I have a default style for all buttons and I'm setting it like this.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Default">
     <item name="buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>
```

My button style is

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/myfont.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

I want this button style to be applied to all buttons without me calling the @style attribute. Everything seems to work fine except for the font. It's not getting applied.

If I call using the @style attribute, it seems to apply the font.

I can apply the font for all the texts in the application using textAppearance, this changes the font of my button as well. but this is behaviour I don't want.

So, how can I apply a custom to buttons through my lib without explicitly using the @style attribute on every button.

Comment: how about create custom widget?

Comment: @deadfish I don't want to create a custom button as it'll be a little more effort when I'm creating my layouts. Instead of just dragging and dropping a button and then aligning it, I'll have to type out my full package name + button class. If there is no other solution, then I'll go with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I've found the problem. If you are using AppCompat the font wont be applied to some widgets like Button, because AppComat replace the components with AppCompat versions when inflating (e.g. Button--->AppCompatButton).

So you can't do do it using only xml. A possible way using Java would be:

```
private void changeFont(ViewGroup layout) {//Where 'layout' is the parent
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            changeFont((ViewGroup) child);
        } else if (child instanceof Button) {
            child.setTypeface(...//The font that you want
        }
    }
}
```

Another option, if your minSDK>16 is avoid using AppCompat. I haven't tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562451/5242950) but it shoul work

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I really really want to avoid Java code. I want my styling done in XML. And I feel applying @style for every button is a better approach than going through every view.

Comment: I see... Are you sure that you have set properly your custom theme in the AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Yeah, I have selector background for the style which is being applied fine. So the theme is applied.

Comment: I think that I've found the problem. If you are using AppCompat the font wont be applied to some widgets like Button, because AppComat replace the components with AppCompat versions when inflating (e.g. Button--->AppCompatButton).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. That was the problem. If you post this as the answer, I'll accept it. I also had to change in the theme "<item name="buttonStyle">@style/myButton</item>" to <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButton</item>.

Comment: I got rid of the appcompat in the default theme, it works fine through XML. But this breaks a lot of other stuff :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out.

Comment: @AkasH check my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I can't fully remember, but we don't pipe in the default styles into Calligraphy if AppCompat is on the Class Path. Subsiquently you will probably need to do this:

```
new CalligraphyConfig.Builder().setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf")
        .addCustomStyle(AppCompatButton.class, R.attr.buttonStyle)
        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
        .build());
```

Take note of the line:

```
.addCustomStyle(AppCompatButton.class, R.attr.buttonStyle)
```

This will tell Calligraphy to use the `buttonStyle` for `AppCompatButton`'s by default. Then you can use:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Default">
     <item name="buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found purely theme-based solution (using `2.2.0` version of the library):

**styles.xml**

**Raised button**

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RaisedButton</item>
</style>

<style name="RaisedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</item>
    <!-- extras -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceButtonColored</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearanceButtonColored" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

**Flat button**

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearanceButtonBorderless</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearanceButtonBorderless" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</item>
    <!-- extras -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_borderless_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

So there is difference where "fontPath" param for flat and raised buttons should be written to.